# printf from char* doesn't work VS2013 C++

Tags: c++, string, char

I am trying to access a char* from inside an injected Dll.
But somehow it doesn't wanna printf()...
The pointer is right, I got it to print earlier today (was using some weird format).

works (so it must be something wrong with the pointer?):

```
char* TestStr = "dsds";
printf("%s \n", TestStr);
```

doesn't work:

```
int ClientDll = (int)GetModuleHandleA("client.dll");
int RadarBase = *(int*)(ClientDll + 0x4E8395C);
int Temp = *(int*)(RadarBase + 0x14);
int LastText = *(int*)(Temp + 0x11C);//Getting the right pointer from memory
printf("%s \n", (char*)LastText );
```

Comment: So the string is null terminated?  That is what the "%s" is expecting.  Also, all of this casting doesn't help.  You should print out, integer by integer, what LastText is in a straightforward loop, and scrap the `printf` for now.   Then you will know if you're giving nonsense to `printf` to print, or the integer sequence is actually a sequence of printable ASCII characters.  As to your title, it is misleading as `printf` works all the time.  The issue is what you give it to work with.

Comment: according to my hexdump this shouldn't be the case...

`3C 00 66 00 6F 00 6E 00 74 00 20 00 63 00 6F 00 6C 00 6F 00 72 00 3D 00 22 00 23 00 66 00 66 00 64 00 66 00 39 00 33 00 22 00 3E 00`

Comment: That hex dump shows that the string uses 16 bit characters, not 8-bit ASCII characters. The "%s" stops at the first 0 *byte*, and the first one it sees is after `0x3C`. The string has all the earmarks of being a wide character string due to the interspersed 0 byte after every non-zero byte, in other words it is `L"<font color="#ffdf93">` -- note the `L` to denote a wide string literal. Your output using `%s` should have shown a single `<` instead of the full string. If you led with that in your post, the error would have been obvious to others right up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a wide char. I had to use `%ls`.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that those offsets that you have (0x....) are correct.  In the context of an addition to an integer pointer, they will be scaled up by the appropriate factor, *viz.*, four.  If those are supposed to be hard constants that represent literal byte offsets, you will be inappropriately multiplying each one of them by four (assuming 32-bit integers).

On top of all that, what is all this nonsense with int *this and int *that and endless castings here and there?  If all you want is a specific address that is 0xThisMany + 0xThatMany + 0xNextGap bytes from a certain base address, then you should just add them together and do one calculation.

That's probably the first, as well as foremost, of your difficulties.

Comment: You are totally wrong! I am dereferencing... also the address of lasttext is okay. i checked in olly